# blocking signal

Tags: linux, ipc, signals

What is the default behavior of signal handler. While it executes, does it block the same signal ?

Regards,
Jrp.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the contents of the `sa_mask` item and the presence of `SA_NODEFER` in the `sa_flags` item of the `struct sigaction` passed to [`sigaction(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction).

Comment: Ignacio,  That's true, but in case if i use signal(), then what is the default behavior ? and, it is possible to invoke sleep() operation inside the signal handler ?

Comment: When using `signal(2)` to set a handler then the behavior is undefined, for the C++ definition of "undefined". According to the `signal(7)` man page it is safe to use `sleep(3)` in a signal handler. Really, this is all in the docs.